# Implementing third party API resources in a custom rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am a student studying web development at a prominent bootcamp in the United States. For my capstone project, I have decided to try and build a fairly simple application wherein one authenticated user can send an amount of Bitcoin to another user (I described to my teacher as a bottled tipping platform).  While this sounds simple in theory, there are many points at which I am worried about tripping up.

I am building this application with rails, using the [Coinbase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?ruby). At my school, we have been taught rails with a fairly strict MVC architecture. Herein is where I have found my first problem. Regarding resources, we have essentially been building from scratch; this will mark my first time attempting to implement a third-party API on the back end. I have noticed in the Coinbase documentation that there are multiple clearly defined resources which I would need to use. The most notable resources are users and accounts (I scaffolded accounts as 'profiles', but they serve the same purpose in an ERD).

If I am working with these pre-built resources, do I need to fully scaffold them, or can I simply import them into my files, then custom write the code to my specifications? If so, would it make sense for me to simply rip up my scaffolding and start from scratch? More broadly, how should I go about fitting pre-existing resources into my MVC architecture?

Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to use Stripe for an example because their docs are the best:

Inside your Rails app, you have a `User` model. For the sake of this example, your User has an `id`, `email`, and `stripe_customer_id`

`user.rb`:

```
before_create :create_stripe_customer

def create_stripe_customer
  stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => "your@email.com",
  ) 
  self.stripe_customer_id = stripe_customer.id
end

def stripe_customer
  @stripe_customer ||= Stripe::Customer.find(self.stripe_customer_id)
end
```

Using `before_create` against an external API is frowned upon ("what if it timeouts or errors?") but for the sake of learning what to do, it's fine.

If you're asking "should I replicate all the data in my own database?" the answer is no; let the API do the work, but cache the results and make sure you don't block your app's requests with external API requests.

Comment: I think its becoming a bit clearer. The `Stripe::Customer.create` is accessing the resource and using its method. So If I wanted my user to create a wallet, for example, I'd need to call `Coinbase::Wallet::Client.create_account`.

Honestly, I'm not sure if I was asking about replicating the data on my database. Am I correct to guess that the result of the `Stripe::Customer.create` call is stored on their database rather than my own, and that I should only keep the necessary to call to their database on my own (which is what you appear to be doing in the `stripe_customer` method)?

Comment: Exactly that. It sends the data to their server (via an HTTP request) for them to store. Let your API provider (Coinbase, Reddit, Stripe) handle the data models (don't reimplement what they already do) while you handle the business logic as it pertains to you interacting with their interface.

Comment: Cool, I have a few more miscellaneous concerns about writing this code out as well: 1.) Am I correct to guess that, when interacting with a third party api, I don't really need to touch the controller, as most of the heavy lifting is dealt w/in the model? 2.) I already have the Gem installed, but I am unsure of where I should put the require statement. My intuition says outside the class definition, at the very top of the file, but I am far from confident about this. 3.) Should the models interacting w/coinbase descend from ActiveRecord, or will I need a different superclass?

Comment: Purists will tell you that your logic belongs in a service object, but for the sake of "learning", it's fine to put it anywhere you can reuse it without having to copy/paste/change (so, not controllers; models are just fine for this)

RE: require — see http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-does-rails-handle-gems/ 

Using ActiveRecord is fine; if you want to get fancy (and really please purists), use a PORO and couple them with some presenters (which can also be POROs); descend from there.

Comment: Alright, This has been very helpful for me. I think I am in a good position to actually start working on my project. Thank you so much!